# PKIX path build error: Not sure I'm creating keystore correctly

Tags: java, validation, security, ssl

I'm getting the following error:

> javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
>       at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Unknown Source)
>       at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(Unknown Source)
>       at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Unknown Source)
>       at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Unknown Source)
>       at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(Unknown Source)
>       at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(Unknown Source)
>       at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Unknown Source)
>       at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Unknown Source)
>       at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(Unknown Source)
>       at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(Unknown Source)
>       at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)
>       at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)
>       at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(Unknown Source)
>       at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(Unknown Source)
>       at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
>       at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
>       at com.towerdata.api.personalization.TowerDataApi.getJsonResponse(TowerDataApi.java:246)
>       at com.towerdata.api.personalization.TowerDataApi.queryByEmail(TowerDataApi.java:101)
>       at EmailActivityMetricsRequestor.requestTowerData(EmailActivityMetricsRequestor.java:57)
>       at EmailActivityMetricsRequestor.Requestor(EmailActivityMetricsRequestor.java:44)
>       at Main.main(Main.java:21)
>   Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
>       at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(Unknown Source)
>       at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(Unknown Source)
>       at sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Unknown Source)
>       at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.validate(Unknown Source)
>       at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(Unknown Source)
>       at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(Unknown Source)
>       ... 17 more
>   Caused by: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
>       at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.engineBuild(Unknown Source)
>       at java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder.build(Unknown Source)
>       ... 23 more

I have done the following:

- I updated to JRE8 thinking that the CA might be old
- Changed JRE8 to my build path in eclipse. The first time I did this, it fixed my issues and I was able to make HTTP requests until I closed out of eclipse. Got the same error again after that.
- Downloaded their root cert through google chrome and tried adding it to the keystore by doing the below command (using windows, ran cmd.exe in admin mode)
- I also tried running Eclipse in Admin mode

When I get the details on the websites security that I'm making requests to, 3 certs come up. The rootca, an intermediate, and a 3rd. Do I need all of those certs to make a valid keystore? If so how do I do that. I used the following code below to make a keystore for the rootca but that hasn't fixed my issues.

```
.\keytool -import -trustcacerts -keystore cacerts -storepass changeit -noprompt -alias alex -file C:\Users\Alex.cauthen\Documents\CA1.cer
```

EDIT: Also, I'm calling this server's API, meaning I call a method and it makes a request for me. I contacted their support team and they said no one runs into this issue. I don't know if that information is helpful.

javax.net.debug=ssl output for when unsuccessful:

> %% Invalidated:  [Session-1, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA]
>   main, SEND TLSv1 ALERT:  fatal, description = certificate_unknown
>   main, WRITE: TLSv1 Alert, length = 2
>   main, called closeSocket()

Output for when it is randomly successful:

> *** Finished
>   verify_data:  { 0, 221, 45, 195, 129, 216, 158, 173, 83, 221, 170, 52 }
>
> ---
>
> %% Cached client session: [Session-1, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256]
>   main, WRITE: TLSv1.2 Application Data, length = 264
>   main, READ: TLSv1.2 Application Data, length = 241

Comment: I am also facing the similar issue with SSL when multiple SSL enabled applications communicate inside one tomcat.
Just check https://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/06/java-security-tutorial-step-by-step-guide-to-create-ssl-connection-and-certificates.html, if you have not gone through.

Comment: SSL with Self signed certificates do give tough times to developers :)

Comment: @Azim This is not a self-signed certificate, but if you're having trouble with one, the simple solution is not to use them. They certainly cause more trouble than they are worth, which is zero.

Comment: Assuming the `cacerts` you added to is the one in your JRE/lib/security, make sure that is the JRE you are running -- if running in Eclipse remember the run-config can specify a different JRE than the buildpath; check the Debug pane to see exactly what ran (even for a Run operation not a Debug operation). If you have (or can get) openssl, do `openssl s_client -connect host:port -servername host -showcerts` into a file and look at each cert to see exactly what the server is sending; if not the output from sysprop `javax.net.debug=ssl` includes the same info but is more work to decode.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 so I was running the wrong JRE. Oddly enough when I changed the JRE to the correct one, it worked once. I ran my code a 2nd time and I got the same PKIX exception. I'll look into the other information.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 I added the javax.net.debug=ssl to my code. Is there anything in specific I should be looking for. I've added what was at the end to my post.

Comment: Based on your selfanswer I assume this is now obsolete, but since I don't like to leave things hanging: the `javax.net.debug` output should begin with a few setup lines and then a (usually long) list of `adding as trusted cert:` and just above sending `certificate_unknown` it shows the server's `** Certificate chain` as received. Comparing the top/last cert in the received chain with the list of local trusted certs would show where the problem is :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I made a very silly error. I did not specify the correct path to cacerts in the command line, so it was creating a folder cacerts in the current directory rather than in the security folder.

Answer (score 2):

You only need to import the root CA certificate, and the command line you're using is correct. So it must be that you're not actually using that file as the trust store. You need to either set the `javax.net.ssl.trustStore` property to its location or initialize an `SSLContext` with a `TrustManager` that it has been loaded into, and proceed from there.

Comment: You _should_ only need the root in your truststore, but it's conceivable the server is not sending the intermediate as it should, and Chrome can fill it in (AIA or cache) while JSSE can't.

Comment: Can you explain a little more on how I do this?

Comment: I did the following with no success: System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", "C:/Program Files (x86)/Java/jre1.8.0_91/lib/security"); It is also worth mentioning that I am using an API provided by the server to make requests. I contacted their support team and they don't ever see people with this issue.

Comment: @AlexCauthen That's the default value for `javax.net.ssl.trustStore`, or rather that's where it will look if you don't specify it, but that isn't where you imported the certificate to. See the [tool documentation for `keytool`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/keytool.html). By default it uses `$HOME/.keystore`.